# Use a Node Lambda function to parse an email stored in an AWS S3 Bucket by SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, email-parsing

**Here's the section of the Node Lambda function that gets the email stored in S3. How do I just get the 'text/plain' content from the returned data object?**

Do I need to include an NPM email parsing dependency with the lambda function (uploaded as .zip) or should I use some regex in the lambda to get the section I want? If so what would that look like?

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    var sesNotification = event.Records[0].ses;

    // Retrieve the email from your bucket
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: "ses/"+sesNotification.mail.messageId
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            callback(err);
        } else {

            data

        }
    });

};
```

Comment: If you are deploying Lambda package as a ZIP file and upload, You need to include both your custom JavaScript code and any dependencies that your code needs to run.

The root of the ZIP file should contain javaScript code you've written, and a directory called node_modules. Inside the node_modules directory where in all the dependencies your code needs.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me get it working.

Answer (score 6):

It would be safer to use `mailparser` package for parsing.

```
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

simpleParser(data, (err, mail)=>{
        console.log(mail.text);
})
```